# Minimum iOS SDK Version for iOS 15

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, enterprise

The minimum iOS SDK requirement for apps submitted to the App Store at present is [iOS 14 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=ib31uj1j)

Is there a minimum supported iOS SDK version in general for devices running iOS 15?

For example for enterprise apps not distributed via the App Store?

Comment: Does the apps you are distributing have to go through approval via Apple?

Comment: No, there's no formal approval process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [Apple SDK compatibility page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/).

The minimum SDK which targets iOS 15 is iOS 9 starting with Xcode 13.

The minimum SDK which targets iOS 16 is iOS 11 starting with Xcode 14. So by some time in April 2023 (when Xcode 14 will be required to submit apps), you will not be able to support iOS versions earlier than iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a minimum supported iOS SDK version in general for devices running iOS 15?

No.

But you would need to make sure that the built app is able to run on iOS 15 and able to make use of the desired iOS platform features.

Also keep in mind that neither iOS 15, nor the iOS 15 SDK is public yet, and the APIs and features are liable to change.